# Example of a Power Series Given Interval of Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

This was a thought question assigned to our calc II class, and I wasn't sure how to approach it.

> Give an example of a power series whose interval of convergence is $(0, \frac{4}{3}]$.
>       Show that it has this interval of convergence.

Comment: Try $\sum \frac{(x-2/3)^n}{n}$. It is by the way not quite right, but the fix should not be hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with
something I know
and see if I can get to
what you want.

First of all,
you want a series
that converges on
a half-open interval.
The simplest one I can
think of is
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$
which converges for
$-1 \le x < 1$.

To make this converge
at the upper limit,
change the sign of $x$
so the series becomes
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n}$
which converges for
$-1 < x \le 1$.

The interval of convergence
is $2$
($=1-(-1)$).
To make it $4/3$,
multiply $x$
by
$\frac{2}{4/3}
=\frac{3}{2}
$.
The series then becomes
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-3x/2)^n}{n}$
which converges for
$-\frac23 < x \le \frac23$.

Finally,
you want the
interval of convergence
to start at $0$
instead of $-2/3$.
To do this,
subtract
$2/3$ from $x$,
making the series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-3(x-2/3)/2)^n}{n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-3x/2+1)^n}{n}
$
which converges for
$0 < x \le \frac43$.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (the incorrect answer previously given was due to a careless reading):

Take the Taylor series of $ln(x+1)$, which has an interval of convergence of $(-1, 1]$. Then substitute $x$ with $\frac 32 x - 1$ in the series.

Comment: So, you wind up with pretty much the same answer as marty cohen's.